# How to separate values from a list using commas in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Situation: I have a code that exports turtle coordinates according to the code below:

```
to path
  file-open (word fileName ".csv")
  file-print (word self xcor " " ycor)
  file-close
end
```

The result is something like:

```
(turtle 1)[1 1 1 1 1 2] [4 4 4 2 1 5]
```

Question: How can I export this same list, but with its items separated by commas?
From `[1 2 1 1 1]` to `[1,2,1,1,1]`, for example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not aware of a convenient way to do that in NetLogo. While you wait for someone who possibly knows that, may I suggest that going from `[1 2 1 1 1]` to `[1,2,1,1,1]` might be easier to do with other programs if you're using them to treat your data?

Comment: When I worked with netlogo for my thesis, I had a companion program in an OO language (I used C# but you could use java, python) to do data manipulation like this. Might be the easier option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to process this in R or something after the fact, I'd recommend potentially reporting in long format (ie, each line indicates a turtle, a tick [or similar], and the coordinates)- I find it simpler to process.

To answer your actual question- one way would be to manually collapse each list of coordinates into a string separated by commas. For example, see the toy model below.

Simple setup:

```
extensions [csv]

globals [ test ]

turtles-own [ xcor-list ycor-list ]

to setup 
  ca
  crt 10 [
    set xcor-list []
    set ycor-list []
  ]
  repeat 5 [
    ask turtles [
      rt random 90 - 45
      fd 1
      set xcor-list lput pxcor xcor-list
      set ycor-list lput pycor ycor-list
    ]
  ]    
  reset-ticks
end
```

This reporter is what's actually doing the work of collapsing the list into a simple string for output:

```
to-report collapse-string-list [str-list]
  report reduce word ( sentence map [ str -> word str ", " ] but-last str-list last str-list )
end
```

And this chunk pulls the desired turtle variables into a list of lists, calls the `collapse-string-list` reporter on them, then exports to a csv:

```
to output-coord-file
  let all-turtles sort turtles
  
  ; Pull coordinates from each turtle
  let who-coord-list map [ 
    current-turtle ->
    (list 
      [who] of current-turtle 
      collapse-string-list [xcor-list] of current-turtle
      collapse-string-list [ycor-list] of current-turtle
  )] all-turtles
  
  ; Add headers
  set who-coord-list fput ["who" "x" "y"] who-coord-list
  
  ; Export
  csv:to-file "toy.csv" (map [ row -> (map [i -> (word i)] row ) ] who-coord-list)
end
```

Output:

[image]